# What are the ways to consume utm_* parameters in referrer, when sending a traffic to the Play Store

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, google-play-services

When sending a traffic to the Google Play Store, the standard way is to populate the `referrer` field (in URL) with an optional set of parameters (such as `utm_source`, `utm_campaign` and others - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en).

What are the standard ways to consume them? One is known to me and this is the API to the Play Store. Are there any other ways? For example, are those parameters currently interpreted by the Play Store and are presented somewhere in the Play Store UI/analytics etc? Are they presented anywhere else (if yes, then where and how - seeing a screenshot would be the best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I juste implement this feature in an Application.

Here is the documentation : [Google analytics Campaign documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#google-play-campaigns)

And the testing documentation : [Google analytics Campaign testing](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns)

The short way is to add these line to the manifest :

```
<!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
<service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This Receiver and Service will automatically send all the information to your Google Analytics.

You can display these information into Google Analytics->Acquisition/Google Play Referral Flow

Comment: So, do I need to use the code above to see these ``utm`` params in Google Analytics for Mobile? Or this is only for the app and the integration with GA is a different "path"?

Comment: I think Google Play send all utm_* params to your application after an installation (broadcast of an intent INSTALL_REFERRER). The Receiver and Service will forward these params to Google Analytics (not sure I understood your question).

Comment: my question was about who will forward the utm params to Google Analytics? Is it the App or some direct integration? Does Google Analytics receive the data from the Play Store or from the app? is the question clearer now? :)

Comment: Play Store web site and your App. Play store web site forward information about [Play Store View]. Your app probably forward the remaining information.

Answer (score 2):

You can see UTM tagged traffic in the [new "User Acquisition"](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/TCgp7c4YLBZ) section of the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish). There is [some help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6263332) on the feature. FYI the report only allows you to see values for `utm_source` and `utm_campaign`.

You may also find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrR6o5tYMWQ) about the feature useful.

[image: User Acquisition tab on Google Play Developer Console]